# ¿Alguna forma para agilizar estos datepickers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datepicker, jquery-datepicker

Necesito utilizar **16** datepickers en una sola página, pero al momento de abrir la página me tarda en cargar, aún incluso probando en local con los JS y CSS (datepicker-bootstrap.js, datepiker-bootstrap.css, etc) en la misma carpeta, no referenciados de Internet (http). ¿Alguna forma para agilizar estos datepickers?

Éste es mi código:

```js
$('.datepick').each(function() {
  $(this).datetimepicker({
    language: "es",
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii",
    autoclose: true
  });
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>




<table style='border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px'>
  <tr>
    <td>Primer seguimiento:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='width:200px'>
      <input name="f1_fecha_1a" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td style='width:200px'>
      <input name="f1_fecha_2a" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Segundo seguimiento:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_1b" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_2b" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tercer seguimiento:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_1c" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_2c" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Revisión:</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_1d" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_2d" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>


<table style='border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px'>
  <tr>
    <td>Primer seguimiento (2):</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='width:200px'>
      <input name="f1_fecha_1a" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td style='width:200px'>
      <input name="f1_fecha_2a" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Segundo seguimiento (2):</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_1b" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_2b" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tercer seguimiento: (2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_1c" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_2c" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Revisión: (2)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_1d" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>
      <input name="f1_fecha_2d" type="text" class="datepick" required>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer que tu código sea ejecutable, pero no hay modo. El código que compartes está incompleto y no funciona por sí solo, te faltan añadir bibliotecas (y especificar mejor cuáles estás usando, porque etiquetas [tag:jquery-datepicker] pero luego en el código tienes `bootstrap-datetimepicker`). Por favor, lee cómo crear un [mcve] y [edit] la pregunta con uno.

Comment: claro amigo ya edite la pregunta y puse las librerias

Comment: He puesto tu código como ejecutable, sigue dando fallo porque falta Moment.js. Le he añadido Moment.js, ahora da fallo porque `language` no es una opción válida para Bootstrap Datetimepicker. Con el código que compartes no es que vaya a ir lento, es que no va a ir directamente. Por favor, crea un [mcve] para que veamos cómo falla el programa, porque con lo que compartes, no se puede reproducir el problema.

Answer (score 0):

No lo he probado para optimizar el tiempo de carga, pero quizás [Arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive) te pueda ayudar, ya que inicializarias el datepicker al momento en que el componente se agrega al DOM.

```
$(document).arrive('.datepick', function () {
  $(this).datetimepicker({
    language: "es",
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii",
    autoclose: true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bootstrap datetimepicker `!=` Boostrap datepicker

El problema es que importaste la librería `bootstrap-datetimepicker` en el HTML pero usaste la documentación de `bootstrap-datepicker`, por lo que le estas pasando claves y valores que no existen o en el formato inadecuado a la hora de configurar los selectores de fecha (o datepicker).

Por ejemplo: no existe la opción autoclose en datetimepicker y el formato de fecha/hora se describe de una manera diferente en ambas librerias.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zttnLvj7/)

---

**Enlaces de interés:**

- Bootstrap 3 Datetimepicker: [Github](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) / [Documentación](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)
- Bootstrap datepicker: [Github](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) / [Documentación](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Datepicker</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h4>Primer seguimiento:</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Desde</label>
                    <input name="f1_fecha_1a" type="text" class="form-control datepick" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Hasta</label>
                <input name="f1_fecha_2a" type="text" class="form-control datepick" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h4>Segundo seguimiento:</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Desde</label>
                    <input name="f1_fecha_1b" type="text" class="form-control datepick" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Hasta</label>
                <input name="f1_fecha_2b" type="text" class="form-control datepick" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h4>Tercer seguimiento:</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Desde</label>
                    <input name="f1_fecha_1c" type="text" class="form-control datepick" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Hasta</label>
                <input name="f1_fecha_2c" type="text" class="form-control datepick" required>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h4>Revisión:</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Desde</label>
                    <input name="f1_fecha_1d" type="text" class="form-control datepick" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Hasta</label>
                <input name="f1_fecha_2d" type="text" class="form-control datepick" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        //! moment.js locale configuration
        //! locale : Spanish [es]
        //! author : Julio Napurí : https://github.com/julionc

        ;(function (global, factory) {
        typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined'
           && typeof require === 'function' ? factory(require('../moment')) :
        typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['../moment'], factory) :
        factory(global.moment)
        }(this, (function (moment) { 'use strict';


        var monthsShortDot = 'ene._feb._mar._abr._may._jun._jul._ago._sep._oct._nov._dic.'.split('_');
        var monthsShort = 'ene_feb_mar_abr_may_jun_jul_ago_sep_oct_nov_dic'.split('_');

        var es = moment.defineLocale('es', {
        months : 'enero_febrero_marzo_abril_mayo_junio_julio_agosto_septiembre_octubre_noviembre_diciembre'.split('_'),
        monthsShort : function (m, format) {
            if (!m) {
                return monthsShortDot;
            } else if (/-MMM-/.test(format)) {
                return monthsShort[m.month()];
            } else {
                return monthsShortDot[m.month()];
            }
        },
        monthsParseExact : true,
        weekdays : 'domingo_lunes_martes_miércoles_jueves_viernes_sábado'.split('_'),
        weekdaysShort : 'dom._lun._mar._mié._jue._vie._sáb.'.split('_'),
        weekdaysMin : 'do_lu_ma_mi_ju_vi_sá'.split('_'),
        weekdaysParseExact : true,
        longDateFormat : {
            LT : 'H:mm',
            LTS : 'H:mm:ss',
            L : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            LL : 'D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY',
            LLL : 'D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY H:mm',
            LLLL : 'dddd, D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY H:mm'
        },
        calendar : {
            sameDay : function () {
                return '[hoy a la' + ((this.hours() !== 1) ? 's' : '') + '] LT';
            },
            nextDay : function () {
                return '[mañana a la' + ((this.hours() !== 1) ? 's' : '') + '] LT';
            },
            nextWeek : function () {
                return 'dddd [a la' + ((this.hours() !== 1) ? 's' : '') + '] LT';
            },
            lastDay : function () {
                return '[ayer a la' + ((this.hours() !== 1) ? 's' : '') + '] LT';
            },
            lastWeek : function () {
                return '[el] dddd [pasado a la' + ((this.hours() !== 1) ? 's' : '') + '] LT';
            },
            sameElse : 'L'
        },
        relativeTime : {
            future : 'en %s',
            past : 'hace %s',
            s : 'unos segundos',
            m : 'un minuto',
            mm : '%d minutos',
            h : 'una hora',
            hh : '%d horas',
            d : 'un día',
            dd : '%d días',
            M : 'un mes',
            MM : '%d meses',
            y : 'un año',
            yy : '%d años'
        },
        dayOfMonthOrdinalParse : /\d{1,2}º/,
        ordinal : '%dº',
        week : {
            dow : 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
            doy : 4  // The week that contains Jan 4th is the first week of the year.
        }
        });

        return es;

        })));
    </script>

    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('.datepick').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'es'
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```